# How do I return common/generic response object for all controller methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there a way to extend IActionResult so that all controller methods return same response object (ex: CommonActionResult) with
HttpResponseCode, Message and Response object (ex: ObjectOne, ObjectTwo based on the methods initiated)?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<ObjectOne> Get(string id)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<ObjectTwo> Get(string name)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post(AppPost app)
    {
    }
```

How do I extend this?

```
        public class CommonActionResult : IActionResult
        {
        }
```

Comment: Have you had a look at middleware (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2).
Basically you can override the OnActionExecuted method of the controller. But then you would have to do it for all controllers (you can inherit from your own custom controller to get around this).
My suggestion is to use middleware.

Comment: Currently what do you return from individual methods?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya ActionResult<ObjectOne> and ActionResult<ObjectTwo> (of course based on call)

Comment: @Ivan Is there a simpler way for starters? I will explore middleware, but it may take time for me to understand.

Comment: One of the benefits of `IActionResult` is that it allows you to return only what you need. For example, what if the object you're trying to get doesn't exist? In that case the response would be a 404 and no object. In that sense you could say that it already does what you're asking. If you want a method that returns something more specific you could put a private method in your controller and call that from the public method.

Answer (score 1):

you can implement IHttpAction based on you requirements

it's a simple sample :

```
   public class CustomResult<T> : IHttpActionResult
    {

        private readonly HttpRequestMessage _request;
        private readonly T _content;


        public CustomResult(HttpRequestMessage request, T content)
        {
            _request = request;
            _content = content;
        }

        public CustomResult(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            _request = request;
        }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            if (_content==null)
            {
                 var response =_request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType);
            }else
            {
               var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_content, _content.GetType(), new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
                });

                        var response = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, jsonData, JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType);
                        response.Content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            }   
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
```

also you can add extra information to response header look at this sample for more information

https://www.strathweb.com/2013/06/ihttpactionresult-new-way-of-creating-responses-in-asp-net-web-api-2/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a generic return type, use `IActionResult`. That will accept any action result type, such as `OkResult`, `OkObjectResult`, `BadRequestResult`, `NotFoundResult`, etc.

`ActionResult<T>` is just a helper that wraps objects in a result, allowing you to return an object directly, instead of having to wrap it in a result first (i.e. `return obj` vs `return Ok(obj)`. However, when you use that, then you must return that specific object type: the type passed into the `T` generic type param. If you need to return different types, then use `IActionResult` as the return in your method signature, and then just wrap the object in something like `Ok`.

```
public IActionResult FooOrBar()
{
   ...

   if (something)
       return Ok(foo);
   else
       return Ok(bar);
}
```